# Setting textbox text to a old date but not allowing the user to select dates before today for jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a scenario where the HTML textbox can display a date which might be old i.e < today. Now on clicking the textbox the jquery ui datepicker will pop open and should display the min date as today and the end date to some future date. The user should not be able to select any previous date from today.
  Although this sounds simple i am unable to set the text of the textbox to a old date and configure the datepicker to allow selection of dates from today.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property **minDate** in jquery Datepicker by providing numeric offset to 0 that represents the number of days. 
0 for today
-ve value for old dates
+ve value for futire dates

`$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0});`

You can also validate the date at submit by initializing **Date** variable in javascript for comparing that it should equals or greater than today's date.